# Find the least Positive Integer Satisfying $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} \ge 4$

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, inequality

Find the least Positive Integer Satisfying $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} \ge 4$

My try:

I actually applied a Brute Force taking:

$$\int \frac{dx}{x} \ge 4$$
Then we get:
$$\ln x \ge 4$$
Hence
$$x \ge e^4$$

So approximately $n=55$

Is there any better approach?

Comment: A quick code shows that $ n \ge 31$ satisfies the conditions.

Comment: Maybe use the trapezoidal rule to get $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2n}\approx \ln n$$ or something like that?  At least this means you are looking for $n$ such that $\ln n\approx 3.5$.  This gives $n\approx 33$.  I don't know how to improve this yet.

Answer (score 4):

This is a slight variation from Peter's answer. Since at small $n$ we cannot use the form
$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1n=\gamma+\ln{(n)}+O\left(\frac1n\right)$$
directly unless we can control the error term hence we need explicit bounds on the estimate before approximating the series with $\log n$ and $\gamma$. We have

$$ 
\log(n+1/2)+\frac{1}{24n^2}-\frac{1}{24n^3}\leq H_n-\gamma \leq \log(n+1/2)+\frac{1}{24n^2}
$$

Now we can replace $H_n$ with $4$ and use the upper bound to get the minimum lower integer bound as $n_{\min} = 31$.

Comment: I get what you mean but how exactly are you solving the inequality$$\log(n+1/2)+\frac{1}{24n^2}-\frac{1}{24n^3}\leq 4-\gamma \leq \log(n+1/2)+\frac{1}{24n^2}$$

Comment: If you mean to prove the value of $n$ must be an integer $\ge31$ then it is sufficient to use$$\gamma+\ln{(n)}\lt1+\frac12+\frac13+\dots+\frac1n\lt\gamma+\ln{(n)}+\frac1{2n}$$to get that $n_{min}=31$.