# $n$ be the smallest positive integer such that $1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac {1}{4}+\cdots \geq 4$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

$n$ be the smallest positive integer such that $1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} +\frac14+\cdots \geq 4$.

My Attempt : I can show that $ \log(n+1) \leq 1+ \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac {1}{4} +\cdots+ \frac {1}{n}$. And by using this inequality  I can say that the smallest number will be less than $54$. But I can not find the smallest number.

Can anyone please help me by giving some hints.

Comment: What about computing the sum up to $n = 53$?

Comment: How do yo compute sum up to 53?@PaulFrost

Comment: In fact, quick calculations show that  $n=31$

Comment: how you are calculating?@Shailesh

Comment: How about $1+1/2+\ln(n+1)-\ln3$

Comment: See [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) on Wikipedia.

Comment: Maybe do an integral approximation. Maybe that is already what you tried? It is difficult to say because you don't explain where the log comes from.

Comment: See [Bounds for the Harmonic k-th partial sum](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2832848/13130).

Comment: I really Can not understand what you are saying?@Empy2

Comment: The sum is the area under steps of width 1 and height $1/k$.  Log is the area under $y=1/x$, which is slightly below the steps.  Do a few steps first then $y=1/x$ the rest of the way.  That is a closer estimate.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro This only gives $21 \le n \le 53$.

Comment: @Paul Frost: I had no idea it would be that weak of a result for the OP's question! I'm pretty busy with other stuff now, and so I didn't take any time to see how helpful that approximation could be. I have an old manuscript that I suspect gives (with proof) a sufficiently accurate approximation, but unfortunately Math Forum discussion group links aren't working (where it's at; I've cited it several times in the past 8 or so years in Stack Exchange, in fact). Maybe [this 22 March 2001 sci.math post of mine](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/i7ylFWbpNT8) will be of use.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro There are certainly much better bounds than $\ln(n+1) < H_n < \ln(n)+1$, but the effort to prove them is certainly much bigger than to answer to OP's question by a simple calculation. The (poor) upper bound $n \le 53$ shows that this can be done *easily*. Finding the smallest $n$ such that $H_n \ge M$ for a big $M$ doesn't work by calculations, so your approach is of course much better for the general case. By the way, are there good approximations for small $n$?

Comment: I'd like to know where the problem comes from. Were you asked to write a program to calculate $n$? Or is it your own curiosity that created the question?

Comment: @Paul Frost: For small values of $n$ you can use many terms of the standard series obtained from the Euler–Maclaurin summation formula. See [Simple proof of showing the Harmonic number $H_n = \Theta (\log n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/306371/13130) and [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Euler-Maclaurin+%22harmonic+numbers%22+bounds). I notice that $\ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n} - \frac{1}{8n^2} < H_n < \ln n + \gamma + \frac{1}{2n}$ mentioned in the sci.math post I cited can be used (with a good enough value for $\gamma)$ to show that $H_{30} < 4$ and $H_{31} > 4.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Ah, phantastic!

Comment: The probable source of the problem is 9) on page 9 of this [PDF
file](http://kvpy.iisc.ernet.in/main/resources/2017/SB_19-NOV-17.pdf),
a 2017 paper from the KVPY exam (Indian Institute of Science). The
multiple-choice question reads:

Let $n$ be the smallest positive integer such that
$$
1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1n\geq4.
$$
Which one of the following statements is true?
A) $20<n\leq60$
B) $60<n\leq80$
C) $80<n\leq100$
D) $100<n\leq120$.

See [Harmonic series sum approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2986695)
- of which the present question is, sadly, a duplicate.

Comment: Another duplicate: [Find the least Positive Integer Satisfying $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n} \ge 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3403041).

Answer (score 4):

Since I am receiving a lot of flack for my poor use of inequalities, I will try to improve my method. First, note that you are analyzing the Harmonic Series $H_n$ and:
$$H_n \approx ln(n)+\gamma$$
However,
$$H_n < ln(n) +\gamma$$ 
For all $n$. Luckily,
$$H_n \approx ln(n) +\gamma - \frac{1}{n}$$
and
$$H_n > ln(n) +\gamma - \frac{1}{n}$$
for all $n$, so we have
$$ln(n) +\gamma + \frac{1}{n}<H_n<ln(n) +\gamma$$
If you want to see just how good these approximations are, look at them all graphed: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/a5ibmgvsdy

We would like to show for which the smalles value of $n$, $H_n \leq 4$ so lets solve both sides of the equality for $4$.
$$4<ln(n) + \gamma$$
$$4- \gamma < ln(n)$$
$$e^{4-\gamma}<n$$
$$30.6546491214 \lessapprox n$$ 
Now for the other side
$$ln(n) +\gamma - \frac{1}{n}<4$$
$$ln(n)-\frac{1}{n}<4-\gamma$$
And after analyzing the graph of $ln(n) + \frac{1}{n}$ (since $n$ isn't separable)
$$n \lessapprox 31.6$$
So finally we have
$$30.6546491214\lessapprox n \lessapprox 31.6$$
Therefore if $n$ is an integer, we can approximate
$$H_{31} \geq 4$$

I put this into Desmos for you as well so you can verify it is true: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ttjyfn6ph3

Comment: How do you switch from $\approx$ to $\ge$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust well I took the ceiling of the answer anyways, but I'll go ahead and fix it if it bothers you

Comment: In fact, $\ln(n)+\gamma<H_n$ for all $n$. Your $ \gtrapprox$ does not hold. We even have $\lceil\ln(11)+\gamma\rceil<\lceil H_{11}\rceil$.

Comment: Still $H_{31} \approx ln(31)+ \gamma$ is a good enough approximation in the context of this problem, hence the correct answer. But I will add another fix to better this I guess

Comment: That doesn't allow you to write wrong inequalities. And as you are looking for a near-integer, the approximation has high chances to be off.

Comment: Okay, so would you like me to add $\frac{1}{n}$ to the approximation?

Comment: Do what you want but don't leave the wrong inequalities.

Comment: As Yves Daoust remarked, we have $H_n > \ln(n) +\gamma$. Instead of $H_n \ge 4$ you look when $\ln(n) +\gamma \ge 4$ which gives $n \ge 30.6546491214$. Thus $H_{31} \ge 4$, but $n = 31$ may not be the smallest integer.

Comment: @PaulFrost Thank you Paul, that makes sense! I think I have cleaned everything up now.

Comment: Grrrr, you still leave the wrong inequality, despite warnings by two guys !

Comment: Sorry, just got back from class, how does the new solution look?

Answer (score 2):

Not assuming as much knowledge about the Harmonic series as the other answers, we can also do an integral approximation by [Riemann sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum).

Since $f(x) = 1/x$ is monotonic decreasing

$$\sum_{k=1}^N 1/k \approx 1+\int_{1}^{N}{\frac{1}x dx} = 1+\left[\log(x)\right]_1^N = \log(N)-\log(1)+1 = 4$$

But because of systematic underestimation due to the monotonic nature of our log function we might as well choose one displaced by one step and get systematic overestimation. The mean value of these will be $$(\exp(3)+\exp(3+1))/2 \approx 37$$

But the nature of this mean involving exponential functions, a geometric mean might be more suitable than an arithmetic mean:

$$\sqrt[2]{e^3 \cdot e^4} = e^{3.5}\approx 33$$

The real value appears to be $31$ or $32$.

Comment: I can not understand this ---
$$\sum_{k=1}^N 1/k \approx 1+\int_{1}^{N}{\frac{1}x dx} = 1+\left[\log(1+x)\right]_1^N = log(N+1)-log(2)+1 = 4$$

Comment: @cmi I added a link to Riemann sum technique.

Comment: I know Riemann sum but  I can not connect this with the Riemann sum.. I think You have made some mistake...@mathreadler

Comment: Some problem in the integration as well.@mathreadler

Comment: Of course you can. This is first calculus class level stuff.

Comment: Maybe you mean I had some arithmetic errors, that is true. I think I fixed them now.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$$ and
$$\frac1x\le\frac1{\lfloor x\rfloor}<\frac1{x-1}.$$

Now integrating between $2$ and $n+1$, and adding $1$,

$$1+\log\frac{n+1}2\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k<1+\log n.$$

The lower and upper bounds equal $4$ for $n=41.17$ and $n=20.09$ and the desired solution will lie in that range.

We can narrow that range by computing more terms explicitly

$$1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\log\frac{n+1}6\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k<1+\frac12+\frac13+\frac14+\frac15+\log\frac n5,$$gives $32.40$ and $27.83$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i=H_n$$
For large values of $n$
$$H_n=\gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac{1}{2 n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
So, using the first term only
$$H_n=k \implies \gamma +\log \left({n}\right) = k \implies n_{(1)} = e^{k-\gamma }$$

Using the first and second term of the expansion, the solution of the equation is given in terms of Lambert function
$$H_n=k \implies \gamma +\log \left({n}\right)+\frac 1 {2n} = k \implies n_{(2)} =-\frac{1}{2 W\left(-\frac{1}{2}e^{\gamma -k}\right)}$$

Some results for a few values of integer $k$'s
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
k & n_{(1)}& n_{(2)} & \text{exact} & H_{n_{(2)}}-k \\
 2 & 4.14866 & 3.6124 &  3.63868 & -6.34\times 10^{-3} \\
 3 & 11.2772 & 10.7654 &  10.7735 & -7.18 \times 10^{-4}\\
 4 & 30.6546 & 30.1505 &  30.1533 & -9.17 \times 10^{-5}\\
 5 & 83.328 & 82.8265 &  82.8275 & -1.21 \times 10^{-5}\\
 6 & 226.509 & 226.008 &  226.009 & -1.63\times 10^{-6}\\
 7 & 615.715 & 615.215 &  615.215 & -2.20 \times 10^{-7}\\
 8 & 1673.69 & 1673.19 &  1673.19 & -2.98 \times 10^{-8}\\
 9 & 4549.55 & 4549.05 &  4549.05 & -4.03 \times 10^{-9}\\
 10 & 12367.0 & 12366.5 &  12366.5 & -5.45\times 10^{-10}
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Hi Claude. Notice that $\log(n)+\gamma<H_n$ so that $n\ge e^{4-\gamma}$ could be wrong (by chance, it is not).

Comment: This shows that $H_{31} \ge 4$, but not that $H_{30} < 4$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. We can do much better at the price of Lambert function which leads to $30+\epsilon$. But you are right. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are good approximations as shown by the previous answers. Doing it intelligently you get *very good estimates*. However, it seems to me that the *exact value* of $n$ can only be determined by explicit calculations. I used Excel:

[image] $\quad$ [image]

Here is the complete table up to $n = 32$. Note that Excel uses $8$ decimals, thus the rounding error in these calculations does not affect our result $n = 31$.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to [Harmonic number - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number),
$$
\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}
\left(H_n - \ln\left(n + \frac12\right)\right)
$$
converges more quickly than
$$
\gamma = \lim_{n\to\infty}(H_n - \ln(n)).
$$
Indeed, in the present case,
$$
e^{4 - \gamma} - \frac12 \bumpeq 30.154649
$$
zeroes in on the answer pretty well.

[Harmonic Number -- from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html)
gives more detail:
$$
\frac1{24(n+1)^2} <
H_n - \ln\left(n + \frac12\right) - \gamma
< \frac1{24n^2}.
$$
These inequalities suffice to determine $n$ exactly, because
\begin{align*}
H_{30} & < \ln\left(30 + \frac12\right) + \gamma + \frac1{21600}
\bumpeq 3.994989, \\
H_{31} & > \ln\left(31 + \frac12\right) + \gamma + \frac1{24576}
\bumpeq 4.027244,
\end{align*}
whence $n = 31.$

The references given in the MathWorld article are:

- DeTemple, D. W. "The Non-Integer Property of Sums of Reciprocals of Consecutive Integers." *Math. Gaz.* **75**, 193-194, 1991.
- Havil, J. *Gamma: Exploring Euler's Constant.* Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press, 2003.

See also:

- Duane W. DeTemple, "A Quicker Convergence to Euler's Constant",
  *Amer. Math. Monthly,* **100**, No. 5 (May, 1993), pp. 468-470.

### Addendum

There are other inequalities that can be used to determine $n$ exactly.

Some are discussed in these books and papers:

- B. Berndt, *Ramanujan's Notebooks, Volume 5,* Springer, New York, 1998.
- T. J. l'A. Bromwich, *An Introduction to the Theory of Infinite Series,*
  Chelsea, New York, 1991.
- E. Cesàro, "Sur la serie harmonique", *Nouv. Ann.* (3) **IV** (1885), 295-296.
- A. Lodge, "An approximate expression for the value of
  $1+\frac12+\frac13+\cdots+\frac1r$",
  *Messenger of Mathematics* **30** (1904), 103-107.
- Mark B. Villarino, "Ramanujan's Approximation to the $n$th Partial
  Sum of the Harmonic Series" (2004),
  [arXiv:math/0402354](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0402354) [math.CA].

The simplest of these results is Villarino's Corollary 3, which is
originally due to Cesàro ("By the way, this was two years before
Ramanujan was born!"), and is given as exercise no. 18 on page 460
of Bromwich's book:
$$
H_n = \frac12\ln(2m) + \gamma + \frac{c_n}{12m},
\text{ where } m = \frac{n(n+1)}2
\text{ and } 0 < c_n < 1.
$$
This gives:
\begin{align*}
H_{30} & < 3.99498717, \\
H_{31} & > 4.02707722.
\end{align*}
For comparison, the exact values are:
\begin{align*}
H_{30} = 4 \times \frac{9304682830147}{9316358251200}
& \bumpeq 3.99498713, \\
H_{31} = 4 \times \frac{290774257297357}{288807105787200}
& \bumpeq 4.02724520.
\end{align*}

Comment: nice and exhaustive answer (+1)